# inserting a node at a certain place in Linked List c++

Tags: c++, insert, doubly-linked-list

I have a linked list and I need to insert a node at the location where the "iterator" is.

below is the insert function(which i have templated):

```
    template <class T>
    void List<T>::insert(T x)
   {
        if (size=0)
       {
           cout << "adding postion to head because empty list" << endl;
          NodeRef newNode = new Node(x);
         tail = head = newNode;
      }
     else
     {
        NodeRef temp = new Node(x);
        temp->previous = iterator;
       iterator->next = iterator;
     }
   }
```

Below is the linked list class (which i have also templated):

```
        class List
         {

         private:
        struct Node
        {
         T data;
         Node* next;
         Node* previous;

            Node() : next(NULL), previous(NULL) {} //define our own default constuctor
         Node(T data) : next(NULL), previous(NULL), data(data) {}
         };

     typedef struct Node* NodeRef;

    NodeRef head;
     NodeRef tail;
     NodeRef iterator; //points to one node at a time
     NodeRef current1;//temp 
    int size;
   public:
    void insert(T);Inserts a new element into the list in the position after the "iterator"
    void scroll() {iterator = iterator->next;}
```

when i call the insert function, i run into problems. the scroll function works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`iterator->next = iterator` is incorrect and creates a loop.  Since the previous line is `temp->previous = iterator`, `iterator->next` should point back at temp.  Once you've updated both links, you should have `n->next->prev == n` for any valid node in the list.